# Putting (pushing?) string data into an Array (or object) - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need some help with my code (clearly). So far I'm able to get the json data that I want but I can't seem to store it in a global array. My goal is to get data.count and data.url in an array like this:

```
var myHelpfulVariable = [
    // e.g. [data.count, '{label:' + data.url + '}']
    [3856, {label:'http://www.google.com/'}],
    [1897, {label:'http://www.yahoo.com/'}],
    [3870, {label:'http://www.microsoft.com/'}]
]
```

I've tried a few different methods using the push function all to no avail. Below is the code that gets the data but it doesn't attempt to put it into an array.

Could someone please help? An explanation of why it works would also be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var getData = [
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com&callback=?',
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.yahoo.com/&callback=?',
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.microsoft.com&callback=?'
    ];

    $.each(getData, function(i,getValue) {

        var urlForGetJSONfunction = "'" + getValue + "'"    

        $.getJSON(getValue,  function(data) {
            $('<div></div>').append('<strong>' + data.count + '</strong>' + ' retweets for: ' + '<a href="' + data.url + '">' + data.url + '</a>').appendTo('body')


            })//ends getJSON

    })//ends each loop
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array.push( obj )` does exactly what you would expect, adds the object to the end of the array. Arrays elements in JS don't have to be of the same type, so you can simply push your data as you get it as follows:

```
var myHelpfulVariable=[];

$.each(getData, function(i,getValue) {

    var urlForGetJSONfunction = "'" + getValue + "'";  

    $.getJSON(getValue,  function(data) {
        $('<div></div>').append('<strong>' + data.count + '</strong>' + ' retweets for: ' + '<a href="' + data.url + '">' + data.url + '</a>').appendTo('body');

        var pair = [];
        pair.push(data.count);
        pair.push({'label':data.url});

        myHelpfulVariable.push(pair);

    });//ends getJSON

});
```

Comment: @alvin `.push()` can take more than one item as arguments, and adds them in the order specified. Calling `.push( [x,y] )` is still taking a single argument though, as it's implicitly creating a JS array and then pushing that into the other array. That is simply an alternative to explicitly creating that 'pair' object.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your question, your `myHelpfulVariable` is defined as an array of arrays, where the inner array contains a numeric value, and an object. If that's what you really want, then here is this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myHelpfulVariable = [];

    var getData = [
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.google.com&callback=?',
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.yahoo.com/&callback=?',
        'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.microsoft.com&callback=?'
    ];

    $.each(getData, function(i,getValue) {

        var urlForGetJSONfunction = "'" + getValue + "'"    

        $.getJSON(getValue,  function(data) {

            myHelpfulVariable.push( [data.count, { label: data.url } ] );


            }); //ends getJSON

    }); //ends each loop
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it didn't seem to work. are you sure that push can accept multiple values? nbrooks' solution creates the pair variable which seems to be required in order to pass 2 values to myHelpfulVariable